# Combining System.IO.Path and System.Uri into a complete system path

Tags: c#, path, uri

Im writing a small web interface for my application and am getting hung on combining a known docs path and the request URI into a absolute local path to retrieve the file from.

For simplicity sake I narrowed my code down to the relevant:

```
string AssemblyDirectory = "C:\MyAppDir\";
string uri = "/index.html";
return new Uri(new Uri(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "http_docs")), uri).AbsolutePath;
```

This will always just return the uri portion only; ie the return is "/index.html", it does not seem to like to combine types of Uri and Path properly. I am aware that simply replacing the "/"'s with "\"'s then doing a simple path.combine would work fine, but I cant help but think there is a .net solution to this somewhere that I am overlooking.

Comment: Fyi. There is `UriBuilder`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanielA.White Even URI builder seems to ignore any parts that are not of type Uri, it still returns just the /index.html portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter is that you have a `/` before your `index.html`. It makes the Uri API to refer to the root of the uri, which gives you at last : `c:\index.html`.

Remove the / in uri  to make it work :

```
string uri = "index.html";
```

Comment: I feel like a fool, thanks for setting me straight, adding a `uri = uri.TrimStart('/');` to my path builder infact did fix everything!